# Masks to segment characters in Opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, image-processing

My algorith it's not working like should be, It is supposed to enclose every letter from a license plate, I have made that:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils import contours

image = cv2.imread('/content/Screenshot_3.png')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")
ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 800 and area > 200:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = 255 - thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
        #cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        ROI_number += 1

cv2.imshow(mask)
cv2.imshow(thresh)
```

`mask` output:

[image]

`thresh` output:

[image]

The original image it's this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your threshold image has letter W and 7 that connect to the white border of the license. If you remove the connections via a better threshold or morphology or some other means, it might work better. The connections are due to the screws in the top of the license place

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your mask tries to keep `W` and `7` into the opposite class due to the connection above. If you tune the threshold you'll see, either you get `F`, `J`, `D`, `2` or `W`, `7`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils import contours

image = cv2.imread('test.png')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8) 
img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1) 

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")
ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 10500 and area > 0:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = 255 - thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
        #cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        ROI_number += 1

plt.imshow(thresh)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, once I change the threshold, I get `W` and `7` but in the negative class and all the other characters are gone.

We can fix this by eroding the threshold before generating the mask.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np
from imutils import contours

image = cv2.imread('test.png')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8) 

thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations=1) # eroding

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")
ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 800:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ROI = 255 - thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
        #cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
        ROI_number += 1

plt.imshow(thresh)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, you can apply some simple processing to get a sharper mask.

Comment: But If I want to apply onther image, ex. https://prnt.sc/skun8d it will doesn't work

Comment: I intend to make a generic program that works for most images

Comment: image processing is not intended to work for every single image, you also need to tune the parameter yourself, I provided one solution, you can't expect me to test every images and find the tuning parameter.

Comment: Just use a deep learning OCR model which doesn't need that many dummy pre-processing steps. The LPs are so clean, any simple model should recognize with high accuracy.

Comment: Thanks! do you recommend any ocr?

Comment: For starter, you can try tesseract english, there is a pytesseract wrapper in python, if that fails, you can try training CRNN models (there are many github repos), if that fails too then you can try object detection approach instead, use yolov3/v4 as it's very fast, there is also tensorflow object detection api.

Comment: Thanks! I already using object detection, I think I will use tesseract, training..